# Trigger for UIWebView webViewDidFinishLoad

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, webviewdidfinishload

Does anyone know what in the html document triggers UIWebView's webViewDidFinishLoad delegate method?

I'm thinking it's document.ready but can't verify.

And if it is document.ready, does it wait for everything inside document.ready to finish before webViewDidFinishLoad is triggered?

Comment: It's document.ready but unfortunately that not always mean that the DOM three has finished. Sometimes there's JS still running in the web thread even when your webview has triggered the webViewDidFinishLoad.

Comment: Thanks artud2000.  Sorry for the late reply.